# Kubernetes Dashboard workload status pie chart colors meaning

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-dashboard

recently I see in our k8s dashboard in the workload status pie chart 3 colors: light green, dark green and red: [pi chart colors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gapMy.png)

Can someone tell me the difference of light and dark green? I couldn't find it in any documentation.

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: second try: In the workload status of my k8s dashboard are some pie charts. And I woulf like to know the meaning of the dark green coloring (see attached screenshot). Thanks!

Comment: I think I figured it out with the help of a colleague: dark green means probably that these pods have a high resource usage.